# Change autocomplete value on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have the bellow code for an autocomplete .I need to change the value of the autocomplete by clicking a button.but the bellow code is not working.

```js
$(function() {
  var countries_starting_with_A = [{
    "id": "1",
    "value": "Afghanistan",
    "label": "Afghanistan"
  }, {
    "id": "17",
    "value": "Albania",
    "label": "Albania"
  }, {
    "id": "18",
    "value": "Algeria",
    "label": "Algeria"
  }, {
    "id": "20",
    "value": "American Samoa",
    "label": "American Samoa"
  }, {
    "id": "22",
    "value": "Andorra",
    "label": "Andorra"
  }, {
    "id": "10",
    "value": "Angola",
    "label": "Angola"
  }, {
    "id": "11",
    "value": "Anguilla",
    "label": "Anguilla"
  }, {
    "id": "23",
    "value": "Antarctica",
    "label": "Antarctica"
  }, {
    "id": "24",
    "value": "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "label": "Antigua and Barbuda"
  }, {
    "id": "25",
    "value": "Argentina",
    "label": "Argentina"
  }, {
    "id": "26",
    "value": "Armenia",
    "label": "Armenia"
  }, {
    "id": "27",
    "value": "Aruba",
    "label": "Aruba"
  }, {
    "id": "28",
    "value": "Australia",
    "label": "Australia"
  }, {
    "id": "29",
    "value": "Austria",
    "label": "Austria"
  }, {
    "id": "12",
    "value": "Azerbaijan",
    "label": "Azerbaijan"
  }];

  $("#field").autocomplete({
    source: countries_starting_with_A,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
    },
    // mustMatch implementation
    change: function(event, ui) {
      if (ui.item === null) {
        $(this).val('');
      }
    }
  });
  $('#setvalue').click(function() {
    $('#field').data('ui-autocomplete')._trigger('select', 'autocompleteselect', {
      item: {
        "id": "29",
        "label": "Austria",
        "value": "Austria"
      }
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<input id="field" type="text" style="width: 200px;">
<button id="setvalue">SET VALUE</button>
```

Comment: it works just fine, Austria id is 29 not 12

Comment: It is not working,You can check by clicking the button

Comment: the selection event triggers just fine, but if you want to dynamically select an option you should manually change the input value as well as trigger select and change

Comment: @hsh my question is about manually selecting the value

Comment: Yes I understand, but you are triggering the select event of auto complete, by invoking select event you can't select an item manually, select event triggers when ever user selects an item, you should write a method to mimic user selection,triggering select event doesn't help.

Comment: @hsh No need,If we comment change() callback ,the selection is working